# How I can use Adrotator, AdDuplex or Admob in a Windows (Phone) 8.1 universal app

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, adrotator

I tried to install Adrotator or AdDuplex for my Windows Phone 8.1 App from NuGet, but I always become this error:

```
Das Paket "AdRotatorWP 1.0.3 // **or AdDuplexWP8 2.8.0.8**" konnte nicht installiert werden. Sie versuchen, dieses Paket in ein Projekt zu installieren, das sich auf "WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1" bezieht, das Paket enthält jedoch keine Assemblyverweise oder Inhaltsdateien, die mit diesem Framework kompatibel sind. Wenden Sie sich an den Paketersteller, um weitere Informationen zu erhalten.
```

I think the packages aren't compatible, but is there any other way to solve this problem? Almost the same when I try to install AdMob.

I hope someone knows an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since last week AdDuplex launched a version of their engine for winphone 8.1 XAML Apps, take a look: http://blog.adduplex.com/2014/06/universal-sdk-for-xaml-apps-windows-81.html

Answer (score 2):

Currently there are no 3rd party advertising sdk available for windows phone 8.1, if you want to add advertisement in your windows phone 8.1 project then you need to use pub enter and this Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone 8.1 [Link to microsoft's SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-windows-sdk%28v=msads.10%29.aspx)